# Is there a way to reposition all vertices so that they are evenly distributed across the mesh?

Tags: vertices

[image]

As you can see in the image, there are small clusters of vertices on my mesh. Is there a way to evenly space all vertices so that all the triangles are the same size across the whole mesh?

Comment: According to the documentation, Blender 2.79 has the [Detail Flood Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html) operation for Dynotopo like the newer versions of Blender. You need to set *Detail Type* to *Constant Detail* and a *Resolution* value. With *Sample Detail Size* (pipette icon) you can sample a value from the mesh.

Comment: @Blunder your recommended technique of 'Detail Flood Fill' has indeed achieved exactly what I am looking for, I thank you greatly for that. However, now my mesh texture is all scrambled up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a *Dyntopo Detail Size* that is about the same size you're looking for, put the brush *Strength* at 0, paint:

[image]

Another method would be to use the *Remesh* tool but it will change the whole topology.

Comment: Excellent, is there a way of retaining texture accuracy too? Because after this, the textures are scrambled up wherever I have used the brush strokes.

Comment: oh ok, I don't know how you can avoid this  :/